# Nsis - changing installation directory

Tags: directory, nsis

Currently I am in my installing directory say c:\Program File\My installer.I have to execute a demo.bat file that is stored at some other location say c:\Program Files\Temp\example.bat,which I have to go at that location and execute coz my example.bat has some support files that are only stored in Temp folder.

**My question is how can I change my installing directory to some other directory, execute demo.bat file and come back to my original installing directory while writing an nsis script?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about "installing directory", I assume you mean current/working directory in the context of a batch file.

```
push $outdir ;save original path
SetOutpath "$programfiles\temp" ;set currect directory
nsExec::Exec "example.bat"
pop $outdir
SetOutpath $outdir ;restore
```

There are several ways to execute a batch file (Expand %comspec% and pass it to Exec/ExecWait, or use one of the exec plugins (nsExec,ExecDos,ExecCmd))